# Pokerstars hands database

Tags: data-request, games

Is there some open data of pokerstars.com hands history?
I'm searching for data that can help me improve my skills about players behavior and strategies.

It can be free or paid sources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I know, buying hands are illegal for several poker sites. However, there are a few free databases that probably will help you.

1) [University of Alberta](http://poker.cs.ualberta.ca/irc_poker_database.html) A database with more than 10 million of poker hands

2) [HandHQ.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20110205042259/http://www.outflopped.com/questions/286/obfuscated-datamined-hand-histories) A 70GB database of poker hands.

Comment: Is the HandHQ data available elsewhere? I'm getting incomplete downloads for some of the zip files from atchive.org. They keep cutting off near ~200mb.